# jQuery: How to completely clone an iframe which' contents were modified by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, clone

Alright, this might be tricky to explain: I have an iframe, let's call it iframe 1, from which I run jQuery to do all kinds of things to its parent, because the iframe is all I can modify for this project. One of the things I do is add an extra iframe (iframe 2) to its parent. The iframe 2 is embedded in iframe 1, and I use jQuery to clone iframe 2 to the parent page (so iframe 1 and 2 become siblings).

The source of iframe 2 however has jQuery of its own, which modifies its contents. The problem is that when I clone iframe 2, it is not cloned with its jQuery modifications intact. I can see in the original iframe 2 contents that its jQuery modifications were succesfull, but the cloning I imagine is being done before those have been able to execute and hence a copy without modifications is made?

Here's some code:

iframe 1 cloning and creating iframe 2

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
$('#article_menu-iframe').clone().insertBefore(parent.document.querySelectorAll("#stock_menu"));
})
```

Now I use the clone method because I am also doing some HTML5 postMessage stuff and the method I tried before (I believe it was .html instead of .clone to create iframe 2) was causing some other issues. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of an iframe like this:

```
$('#article_menu-iframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

From here you can construct a new iframe object with that value (cloning it)

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how you could demo this in JSFiddle :P

Comment: I don't think that will work cross domain? The source of the iframe that is cloned is on another domain you see.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be able to find the contents of an IFRAME in my example here: http://cmzmedia.com/tinymce/examples/simple2.html

Comment: I see.  do you have control of both servers?  You could have the page being loaded inside the iframe report its contents to the outer frame (even if they are in different servers)

Comment: Can you edit this jsfiddle attempt to implement the suggestion you mentioned above? So far it just returns "null." Thanks, I just thought it'd be easier on me and on the OP if a JSFiddle could be edited to work. In the link I gave above to my own server space there's only one domain involved. It doesn't use iframes to link to a different domain but because the TinyMCE rich text editor uses iframes.

http://jsfiddle.net/5QL7W/21/